# cURL to URL for POST by using WebRequest to an API

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have gone thru MSDN and found how to use WebRequest, copied same function and changed values for my need,
But for POSTing i have a cURL which i am not familiar with and i can't convert that as a string to pass thru the variable for POST, can anyone please convert below cURL to a string to the format how it needs to be POSTED to get response from server ?,

This is the example cURL supplied by API team to communicate with server

```
 curl https://api.kite.trade/orders/regular \
    -d "api_key=xxx" \
    -d "access_token=yyy" \
    -d "tradingsymbol=XYZ" \
    -d "exchange=ABC" \
    -d "transaction_type=BUY" \
    -d "order_type=MARKET" \
    -d "quantity=1" \
    -d "product=OLD" \
    -d "validity=DAY"
```

The sub i am using from MSDN :-

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestPostExample
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.contoso.com/PostAccepter.aspx ");
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "POST";

            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            // Get the request stream.
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close ();

            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close ();
            dataStream.Close ();
            response.Close ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `api_key=xxx` etc are parameters. You'll need to add them to the post. A way to do this is to encode them to in the url. `https://api.kite.trade/orders/regular?api_key=xxx&access_token=yyy etc.` (side note: since the api key is in the url this is considered to be bad practice)

Comment: On the other hand, if you want the data to be in the request-body content, you'll need to format the data in a way that's accepted by the host server. This might be JSON or XML.

Comment: Which means when i convert it as url dont need to include those "\" , "-d" etc.. ?, Just put a "?" after the target url and pass parameters seperating them by "&" ?

Comment: Well, yes, but I am not an cUrl expert. Basically you'll need to send some parameters with a post. The `query string` is one way to do it (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) but maybe the host won't accept that form. It might expect SOAP, XML or JSON in the body. You'll have to check that at the host's documentation. If you know which form is accepted you can use that knowledge to do the actual POST.

Comment: Hi Stefen , here is what API documentation says about requests :- "All requests happen over HTTPs. Inputs are form-encoded parameters and responses are JSON unless stated otherwise"

Comment: Check out this post on the code project (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18034/HttpWebRequest-Response-in-a-Nutshell-Part) You will see that the `api_key=xxx&access_token=yyy` structure is similar as `"test=postvar&test2=another"` It should work for you if you use the parameters from curl. Beware; the `&` is not used here.